# ldap_bind() hanging / freezing

Tags: php, openldap

So I have reduced my problem to a simple php script

`test.php`

```
<?php 
  ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7); //for logging
  if($con = ldap_connect( 'ldaps:domain.com', 636 )){
    $bind_return = ldap_bind($con, 'username', 'super_secret_password');
  }
?>
```

When I go to `localhost\test.php`, the browser indicates it is waiting for a response, and will just hang there.... forever (more accurately until I stop it, sometimes an hour later, but you get the idea).  Using xdebug, I'm able to pinpoint the hanging to the `ldap_bind()` call.  When I try to step over or into the ldap_bind() line of code, my xdebug hangs and becomes unresponsive.

The logged output from `ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);` is:

```
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(domain.com)
ldap_bind_s
ldap_simple_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP domain.com:636
ldap_new_socket: 15
ldap_prepare_socket: 15
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying domain.com:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 15 tm: -1 async: 0
```

And then nothing after that.  I'm not sure what to make of it, and Google has not been kind.

`ldap_connect()` is successful, the return is something like `(resource) resource id='2' type='ldap link'`.  `max_execution_time` does NOT interrupt the execution of the script.  If I put something like `while(true){}` before the problematic line of code then the `max_execution_time` will trigger and I will see an error.  So `ldap_bind()` is somehow even stopping the php environment from timing out.  Wrapping the code in a try/catch block does nothing to alleviate the hanging.

I have tried:

1) Restarting the server many, many times

2) Reinstalling php5, php-ldap, libapache2-mod-php5, and apache2

3) Scouring the internet

The funny thing is `ldap_bind()` was working perfectly a few weeks ago, it still works perfectly on my production site, but I've been trying to figure this out for a long while now and am so close to lighting my computer on fire.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

So I installed ldap-utils and ran a `ldapsearch -H ldaps://domain.com`, and it hung.  I ran it with the debugging option `ldapsearch -d 1 -H ldaps://domain.com` and the output was:

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://domain.com/)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://domain.com:636/??base)
ldap_pvt_sasl_getmech
ldap_search
put_filter: "(objectclass=*)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "objectclass=*"
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP domain.com:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying domain.com:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
^^^^It hangs right here^^^^
```

Seems familiar, no? Running an strace on the whole command produces a long trace but hangs at this point

```
write(3, "\26\3\0\0p\1\0\0l\3\3T\254/\31\24\200\25 \247\221\7\251\240\271\35\"\272\203V \305"..., 117) = 117
read(3,
```

Again, it hangs right here, the cursor just blinking after the "`read(3,`"

I came across [this bug report](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200811/msg00012.html) with openldap that is eerily identical to my own problem, down to the strace hanging at the read command.  However, there doesn't seem to be a discussion about solutions as openldap is pointing the finger at gnuTLS.

Comment: Are you able to connect without SSL? Are you able to open a connection if IP address is provided? Note that `ldap_connect` does not perform network I/O, it just allocates a resource. If you are wary of supplying your credentials on unprotected connection, read the root DSE (`ldapsearch -s base -b "" -h domain.com *`), which does not require authenticated connection.

Comment: @RobertRossmann, Unfortunately, the directory I'm trying to connect to doesn't allow a connection without ssl. Something short of booting up a new virtualized ldap server (which I may end up doing anyway) I won't be able to tell. But I think I know where you're getting at, and yes, I too think this has something to do with the certification/ssl combination. Currently trying to see if I'm using gnuTLS, and if so, switch to openssl. This sysadmin stuff is so damn daunting.

Comment: @RobertRossmann, I was able to confirm that ldapsearch works without ssl.  Using a [free online test server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) I was able to connect and receive a response with this command `ldapsearch -x -s base -b "" -h ldap.forumsys.com *`

Comment: Any Update on this issue? I am experiencing the same issue. We changed /etc/openldap/ldap.conf and added line 'TLS_REQCERT never', which allowed us to do ldapsearch from command line successfully, however we are still unable to do it in php

Comment: No, unfortunately.  For me, at least, it had something to do with Debian flavor of linux and whatever server was housing ldap.  The same code would work on Centos just fine, but freeze on my Ubuntu OS.  Never did figure it out. :/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is something environmental.  This could be a firewall change, network route change, SSL Certificate expiration, change in the LDAP server, etc.

I would execute a series of diagnostic protocols working up the ISO stack.

Start with a telnet to port 636 on the remote server.  If that works, download openldap and give that a shot.  See if you can manually connect with that.  If that works run your debug version in production (from the command line) and see what the next step after ldap_pvt_connect is.  Also, try the command line version, you have more finite control of things and you don't have a webserver in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the identical problem here, which came down to a firewall block. The slapd daemon is running on the same server as the web server, so I needed to either specify "localhost" instead of "domain.com" when calling ldap_connect() or add an appropriate rule to the kernel filter table to specifically allow a connection to the server from its own IP address.